# Hierarchical index in data frame missing columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, anaconda

Im trying to learn Pandas by doing different exercises. I created a dataframe that looks like the example below. I'm trying to create a unique id by concatenating the fields, however when i get the data frame  columns i only have fpd as a column. Could someone explain me why i don't see all the columns?

```
monthID  pollutantID  processID  roadTypeID  avgSpeedBinID     Fpd
1        1            1          4           1                1.749101
                                             2                0.935300
                                             3                0.529701
                                             4                0.393052
                                             5                0.306381
                                             6                0.261649
                                             7                0.235040
```

I get the data frame by executing this:

```
fpd =    data['fpd'].groupby([data['monthID'],data['pollutantID'],
         data['processID'],data['roadTypeID'],data['avgSpeedBinID']]).sum()

fp = pd.DataFrame(fpd)
```

Comment: Well you grouped by all those columns so they are now part of the groupings, you have to call `get_group('pollutantID')` or other grouping to get the values

Comment: fp.get_group('monthID')
gets the following error...

attributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '   get_group'

Comment: Sorry it looks they are in the index, try `fp.reset_index()`

Comment: Yeah that worked. Could you refer me to a place where it talks about this. I guess I'm not quite sure what happens to a data frame when is grouped by in the sense that you cant access them as regular columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reset the multiindex to columns by:

```
fp.reset_index(inplace=True)
```